# Is there any way I can develop Android apps on Google Cloud/ AWS?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

I have a laptop that I can't install anything on, I can however go to any web site. I was wondering if there is any way I can make an android app like this. I know about cloud 9 but I can't find any way to make it work for android apps. Is there any way I can make a setup like this work?

Comment: Gradle and Android Studio don't need to be "installed", they can run standalone. Java might already be installed on your computer also. Otherwise, probably cheaper to pay for a development computer than pay for cloud hosted solutions

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try [Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/pay-as-you-go/) which provides you a windows / Linux Virtual Machine as well as Azure tools for your development.

You can either install your tools (Android Studio) there or use the provided [one](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/mobile/android/).

OR

[Macincloud](https://www.macincloud.com/) which provides Android Studio and X-Code (iOS)